# How to build zigzag subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have interest payment table and I want to calculate this using subtraction by zigzag transaction in SQL at first I need to do this below

1. sum (interest) = 3641.18
2. from total interest (3641.18) - interest(998.96),date(2023-07-22) = outstanding(2642.22)
3. then from outstanding(2642.22) - interest(941.69),date(2023-08-22) = outstanding(1700.53) until reach the bottom, date(2023-10-22) become  outstanding = (0)

| acct | date | interest | outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 963 | 2023-07-22 | 998.96 | 2642.22 |
| 963 | 2023-08-22 | 941.69 | 1700.53 |
| 963 | 2223-09-22 | 881.69 | 818.84 |
| 963 | 2223-10-22 | 818.84 | 0 |

I tried this query:

```
Select fc.acct   
  , date
  , interest
  ,SUM(case when DATEDIFF(yy,fc.date, tb.date) <= tb.tb1_start and DATEDIFF(yy,fc.date, tb.date) <= tb.tb1_end 
    then fcalc.outs_interest - fc.interest  else 0 end) AS oustanding      
from table fc 
INNER JOIN (Select acct, Sum(interest) outs_interest from table where GROUP BY acct)fcalc 
ON fcalc.acct = fc.acct
,dbo.axsp_get_timebands() tb
where fc.acct = 963
GROUP BY fc.acct, fc.date,fc.interest,fcalc.outs_interest
```

Output, that I got is like this from:

```
total interest(3641.18) subtract per line
total interest(3641.18) - interest(998.96),(date(2023-07-22)) = 2642.22
total interest(3641.18) - interest(941.69),(date(2023-08-22)) = 2699.49 like that
```

| acct | date | interest | outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 963 | 2023-07-22 | 998.96 | 2642.22 |
| 963 | 2023-08-22 | 941.69 | 2699.49 |
| 963 | 2023-09-22 | 881.69 | 2759.49 |
| 963 | 2023-10-22 | 818.84 | 2822.96 |

**What I was expecting?** is like below:

| acct | date | interest | outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 963 | 2023-07-22 | 998.96 | 2642.22 |
| 963 | 2023-08-22 | 941.69 | 1700.53 |
| 963 | 2023-09-22 | 881.69 | 818.84 |
| 963 | 2023-10-22 | 818.84 | 0 |

Comment: It's not easy to do cross-record processing in SQL, but it's trivial in any programming language.  You should use each tool for its strengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean exactly by "zigzag subtraction", but you can achieve what you want using window function.

`sum(interest) over ()` gives you the total interest which is `3641.18`.

And

`sum(interest) over(order by date)` gives you the running total of interest order by date

```
select *, 
       outstanding = sum(interest) over (partition by acct) 
                   - sum(interest) over (partition by acct
                                             order by date)
from   fc
order by date
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to analyze my concern really appreciated @sqirrel